# Enable absolute imports in mocha tests for babel/react/node application

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, babeljs

I'm working with an existing babel/react/node application which works with absolute import statements for project modules. E.g.:

```
import level from 'state/models/level';
```

I start the server with babel-node

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node server.js
```

Now I've created some mocha unit tests. I call them by

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/test/test_mymodule.js
```

Unfortunately my tests did not work with these imports.
The imports in my tests work only when relative. E.g.:

```
import level from '../state/models/level'
```

But of course I do not want to rewrite all import statements.

So how do I have to configure my mocha tests, that all import statements are interpreted correctly?

My app is located in the src directory.
I've tried to put the tests in the app directory or created a dedicated test directory. Both doesn't work.

A pointer to an existing application which uses babel and mocha would also help.